# how can I switch a value like (06) into (6)?

Tags: javascript

I am having a case in javascript that take a random input like this
(02,05,08,09,10,13,15,18 or ......,99)

then I take this value and use it in another case.

I am having no problem with numbers starting from 10 to 99
my problem is with nos from 01 to 09

Is there anyway in javascript to switch those nos from ex. (06) to (6)

substring(), substr(), slice() is not OK for me.

Comment: `parseInt("06", 10) === 6`

Answer (score 2):

If your random input is integer then parseInt() will give you desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
str = str.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

Or parse the input as a number:

```
str = parseInt(str, 10).toString(); // or
str = Number(str).toString();
```